# String.Format in vb

Tags: vb.net

In VB what is the difference between

```
String.Format("{0:X1}", abyte)
```

and

```
String.Format("{0:X2}", abyte)
```

abyte is of type byte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value after the X specifies the minimum number of characters in the formatted number.

```
String.Format("{0:X1}", 12) => "C"    
String.Format("{0:X2}", 12) => "0C"
String.Format("{0:X3}", 12) => "00C"
String.Format("{0:X4}", 12) => "000C"
String.Format("{0:X5}", 12) => "0000C"
String.Format("{0:X6}", 12) => "00000C"
String.Format("{0:X7}", 12) => "000000C"
String.Format("{0:X8}", 12) => "0000000C"
```

And FYI, the maximum value after X is 99.

Comment: what will be the result of String.Format("{0:X1}", 63)

Comment: @unknown - It would take you all of 5 minutes to test it!  But LFSR's answer should answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString):

> The precision specifier indicates the
>   minimum number of digits desired in
>   the resulting string. If required, the
>   number is padded with zeros to its
>   left to produce the number of digits
>   given by the precision specifier.

Also, this format is only supported for numeric types, so abyte is interpreted as such.

If abyte represents a number greater than F (15 dec), X and X2 are equivalent

```
String.Format("{0:X}",16)  => "10"
String.Format("{0:X2}",16) => "10"
String.Format("{0:X3}",16) => "010"
String.Format("{0:X4}",16) => "0010"
```

and so on